# Add normalScrollElements depends on screen size

Tags: javascript, fullpage.js

I'm using fullpage.js, May I know how to add 'normalScrollElements' only when screen width is less than 991px for example?

I tried different scenarios but it didn't work for me!

```
new fullpage('#fullpage', {
                verticalCentered: true,
                fitToSection: true,
                normalScrollElements: '#FOOD , #foodmenu',               

            });
```

Comment: can you please attach the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

I just write the condition before initializing the fullpage instance!

So I will have two diffrent initializations, first one if screen < 991px and a second one if screen > 991px.